# Change image view scale type and then scaled image show in another image view

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview

change image view scale type and then scaled image show in another image view

ex -

ImageView imageview1 = R.id.imageview1;

ImageView imageview2 = R.id.imageview2;

imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapValue);

imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

**then i want scaled image show in imageview2**

imageView2.setImageBitmap(scaled image)

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for issues/problems with the Android Studio product. This question has nothing to do with the Android Studio product.